# Execute promise or await with generated string variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a mongoose query and storing it in a variable call `query`. The code below shows it

```
let query = "Product.find(match)";
if (requestObject.query.sortBy) {
    query = query.concat(".", "sort(sort)");
    const parts = requestObject.query.sortBy.split(":");
    sort[parts[0]] = parts[1] === "desc" ? -1 : 1;
  }
  if (requestObject.query.fields) {
    query = query.concat(".", "select(fields)");
    const fields = requestObject.query.fields.split(",").join(" ");
    const items = await Product.find(match).sort(sort).select(fields); //.populate("category").exec();
    /**const items = await Product.find(match).sort(sort).select("-__v"); //.populate("category").exec();**/
  }
```

I am facing an issue when attempting to run a mongoose query that I have generated and stored in a string. When I run it in post man, the response is 200 but no data is returned. Below is a `console.log(query)` on line 2

[image: The image shows a log to the console of query on line 2]

what I hope to achieve is to have await or create a new promise execute the content id query variable like shown below

```
const items = new Promise((resolve) => resolve(query)); //.populate("category").exec();
  items
    ? responseObject.status(200).json(items)
    : responseObject
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "Could not find products, please try again" });
```

I will appreciate it very much that and also if you can give me a better way of doing it, I will love that

Comment: What's the problem? What's the question? What's the "query" variable?

Comment: `items` is a Promise, which is a truthy value, so `items ?` evalautes to true and `responseObject.status(200).json(items)` will executed. And `.json(items)`won't work if `json` does not accepts a Promise. Maybe you want to do `const items = await new Promise(`

Comment: @t.niese I did that previously but `items` then becomes a string and it returned to `.json()`. I don't know why promise can't return data. when I log items I get `Promise { 'Product.find(match).sort(sort).select(fields)' }
` I can't understand why it will not resolve `Product.find(match).sort(sort).select(fields)` into data
`

Comment: A Promise can resolve to any value. In your shown code it resolves to whatever `query` contains as value.

Comment: @t.niese So can I make it run the value of query? How can I get it to treat it as a promise not a string

Comment: I don't have any idea what value the `query` variable holds nor how it was created. Create a [mcve] of what you have that would allow reproducing the problem. Or at least allow understanding what `query` contains.

Comment: @t.niese The query if built from a series of `concat` from if conditions. After the query is built to the string and when I `log` it to the console, I get `Product.find(match).sort(sort).select(fields)` which is a mongoose command. So at the end of all the if blocks, I expect to be able to run it as functional command but the promise resolves to a string returning what the variable query holds

Comment: @t.niese Please go through the problem, I have added some new details

Comment: You seem to have created a string containing `"Product.find(match)..."` that represents the code that you want to execute. Instead `Product` should actually be a variable, initialized like `const Product = mongoose.model('Product', yourSchema);` and then your code should execute `Product.find(match)...`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really make sense. You are building a string, not a query. You can't do anything with that string. (You could `eval` it, but you really shouldn't). Instead, build a query object!

```
let query = Product.find(match);
if (requestObject.query.sortBy) {
  const [field, dir] = requestObject.query.sortBy.split(":");
  const sort = {};
  sort[field] = dir === "desc" ? -1 : 1;
  query = query.sort(sort);
}
if (requestObject.query.fields) {
  const fields = requestObject.query.fields.split(",");
  query = query.select(fields);
}

//query.populate("category")

const items = await query.exec();
if (items) {
  responseObject.status(200).json(items)
} else {
  responseObject.status(400).json({ message: "Could not find products, please try again" });
}
```

If you really want to get that string for something (e.g. debugging), build it separately from the query:

```
let query = Product.find(match);
let queryStr = 'Product.find(match)';
if (requestObject.query.sortBy) {
  const [field, dir] = requestObject.query.sortBy.split(":");
  const sort = {[field]: dir === "desc" ? -1 : 1};
  query = query.sort(sort);
  queryStr += `.sort(${JSON.stringify(sort)})`;
}
if (requestObject.query.fields) {
  const fields = requestObject.query.fields.split(",");
  query = query.select(fields);
  queryStr += `.select(${JSON.stringify(fields)})`;
}

//query.populate("category")
//queryStr += `.populate("category")`;

console.log(queryStr);
const items = await query.exec();
…
```